# Why does separating a d3 method chain on enter alter outcome?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am learning D3.js and curious on the chaining of methods

This script works:

```
var data = [32, 57, 112, 250]

var svg = d3.select("svg")

svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cy", 60)
    .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return i * 100 + 30 })
    .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d); })
```

But this script results in nothing:

```
var data = [32, 57, 112, 250]

var circles = d3.select("svg").selectAll("circle");
circles.data(data);

var circlesEnter = circles
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cy", 60)
    .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return i * 100 + 30})
    .attr("r", function (d) { return Math.sqrt(d)})
```

I don't see the different effects on these two different approaches. Can anyone tell me the difference between these?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect the key point I believe you are asking about - if I have erred you can roll my edit back or leave a comment indicating I've lost the intent of the question and I'll undo it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that `selection.data()` doesn't modify an existing selection, it returns a new selection:

> [selection.data] Binds the specified array of data with the selected elements,
>   returning a new selection that represents the update selection: the
>   elements successfully bound to data. Also defines the enter and exit
>   selections on the returned selection, which can be used to add or
>   remove elements to correspond to the new data. (from the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_data))

Also,

> Selections are immutable. All selection methods that affect which
>   elements are selected (or their order) return a new selection rather
>   than modifying the current selection. However, note that elements are
>   necessarily mutable, as selections drive transformations of the
>   document! ([link](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection))

---

As is, `circles` contains an empty selection of circles (size: 0) with no associated data array. Because it is immutable, calling `circles.data(data)` won't change that selection, and `circles.enter()` will remain empty. Meanwhile the selection created by `circles.data()` is lost as it isn't assigned to  a variable.

We can chain methods together as in the first code block of  yours because the returned selection in the chain is a new selection when using `.data()`, `.enter()`, or `selectAll()`. Each method in the method chain uses the selection returned by the previous line, which is the correct one.

In order to break `.data()` from the chain, we would need to create a new intermediate selection with selection.data() to access the enter selection:

```
var circles = d3.select("svg").selectAll("circle");   

var circlesData = circles.data(data);

var circlesEnter = circlesData
  .enter()
  ...
```

```js
var data = [32, 57, 112, 250]

var circles = d3.select("svg").selectAll("circle");

var circlesData = circles.data(data);

var circlesEnter = circlesData
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cy", 60)
    .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return i * 100 + 30})
    .attr("r", function (d) { return Math.sqrt(d)})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

But this would be a bit of an odd approach.

Comment: *"Selections are immutable"*. This requires a `<blink>` HTML element wrapping it.